# What about so.com as a shortcut for stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I have small doubt, it may be silly, for that pardon me. If I want to go facebook.com I will type fb.com in the address bar.

Like that, why can't make stackoverflow.com shortcut as so.com?

Simple idea, user can type the url very fast.

Comment: Because someone else owns it?

Comment: And Facebook probably paid many millions of dollars to get fb.com - I don't think Stack Exchange has that kind of money laying around.

Comment: A Chinese(Chrome told me that) search engine is already hosted on that domain name. Also, you can just bookmark *stackoverflow.com*. After that you need not even type 2 alphabets. Just click on the bookmark and bam, SO has opened up for you.

Comment: i don't know why the down vote has happen? i asked my doubt only right?

Comment: Why does it have to be .com? There's about to be a giant land rush on new extensions. Why not pick one not in use?

Comment: @PandiyanCool down votes means that people disagrees with you, thinks that this is not good idea or necessary.

Comment: @animuson they did, from the American **F**arm **B**ureau Federation. [It was only $8.5MM](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2375643,00.asp).

Comment: I agree with all those who responded. However, the idea itself it not something I can disagree with, so I sincerely don't understand why it's being downvoted so badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, the sarcasm and to-the-point- reasons from replies aside, it is a great idea!
It would be a good thing, and would make life easier, as well as looking pretty good.

However it's just not viable for many reasons. Certainly not when considering the reasons you'd like them to do it.

"stackoverflow.com" is linked in so many places, it would be foolish to change it now. In fact, even if they bought a new domain name they would likely just use it as a convenience thing and redirect the new domain name to the current one.

So is a lot of work, hassle and money for saving users 5 seconds.

**Typing** "Stack" into Google and clicking the top result ("StackOverflow") in the drop down auto results
 = *Less than 10 seconds and free*

**Bookmark** it and click "Bookmarks" and your link to Stack
 = *Less than 10 seconds and free*

**Typing** "stackoverflow.com" into your browser address bar and clicking go
 = *Less than 10 seconds and free*

**Stack** buying a new shorter domain
 = *Months of staff time planning, discussing, researching, coding and developing, probably in the end to just redirect new domain to current URL so not to lose out on years of back links and other internet identification sources etc.

For hundreds of thousands of $£*

Comment: i'm not saying to change it as so or se itself. I just asked my doubt whether it is fine or not?

Comment: Which is fine. Ignore the downvotes, it's not personal just people disagree with the idea ;) As I pointed out by my answer, it's possible and a great idea, but even if they did they wouldn't use it to any advantage of their own really, only save users 5 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

The main problem is that the Internet doesn't work that way. Domain names are just like pizzas - you have to go buy them. As a two-letter name ending in .com, it's probably very, very expensive.

And SE has better things to do with millions of dollars.

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt that's going to happen. Firstly, someone owns it. Secondly, it would be massively, massively expensive, in the range of hundreds of thousands to millions. Also, you should really just use a browser with autocomplete and bookmarks. Keep in mind that Facebook is valued at over $100 Billion, while SO is in the range of millions

Comment: "Keep in mind that Facebook is valued at over $100 Billion, while SO is in the range of millions" This makes me sad

Answer (score 2):

Isn't a global domain name replacement, but can be helpful if you're using Chrome to add an [Omnibox search engine shortcut](http://codinghobbit.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/improve-use-of-chrome-with-omnibox.html)

Just get in there, add an entry with:

```
Search Engine: StackOverflow
Keyword: so
URL: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s
```

Then as soon as you type `so` you will get Chrome to say:

[image]

Which at least lets you search quickly.  There are other ways to get shortcuts on your end via browser or how your local network translates names, if you wanted to do that.  But it won't work for other people in URLs you send.

As for putting more money into the Domain Name Mafia's pockets, I think we could all do with some serious reform instead of encouraging them.  A word should belong to the collective agreements of the people who use it, not some chump who bought a piece of totally-unreal-estate first (or bid the highest for it).  I could rant for hours about that.

Comment: Rant somewhere else, please. :-) MSO is for discussions about SO. Without some sort of domain registration system, the Internet wouldn't work. "Collective agreements" simply wouldn't work in practice, but discussing it here is not the place. The downvotes (like mine) are probably based on the foolishness of that statement in general. "Let's let your home address be defined by the collective agreements of the people that drive by your house." is great, but good luck getting your mail. (No, I'm not a member of the "postal service mafia" either. I just have some common sense.)

Comment: @KenWhite (a) I gave a useful suggestion, (b) I don't see my comment as much different in spirit than *SE has better things to do with millions of dollars*, (c) One paragraph does not count as a rant, if I were ranting it would be much longer than one paragraph, (d) While an agreed addressing system for node identities in a network is necessary to communicate between nodes, a centralized phone book where everyone agrees to direct the same word to a node is not necessary--it can be decentralized and arbitrated according to your local allegiances, else two people couldn't have the same name.

Comment: (a) Your useful suggestion isn't "useful". I do the same thing in Firefox every day; I start it and type `sta` in the location bar, and it helpfully offers `stackoverflow` as the first suggestion. (b) Your comment contributed nothing. (c) Your own words were "rant", which is what I referred to in my comment. (d) A centralized phonebook is absolutely necessary when people **can not have the same name**, which is the case for the Internet. How do you resolve disputes? "I want stackoverflow. No, I want it instead - I don't care you've had it for three years. I have ten more friends. It's mine."

Comment: @KenWhite I said I *could* rant, I didn't say I did.  Two people can have the same name in a phonebook and different phone numbers.  Or same name and different employee ID.  I'd think someone who knew dBase and FoxPro might have some clue about UUID and IPV6 addresses, and techniques for resolving it besides demanding employees change their names because someone else had it first... if you want to talk about this more, then contact me personally.  (*I* have my contact info in my profile.)  And giving a way to type "so blahblah" and get to StackOverflow is useful in light of the question.

Comment: Nah, I'm good. The entire paragraph had no purpose here, and made no sense anyway. But thanks for taking the time to look at my profile and using (a very small, irrelevant part of) it for a personal insult. It shows the level you're at here. I'm not going there. But knock yourself out.

Comment: The question is about a suggestion that "SO gets a new domain name". Your response requires users to A) have and use a specific browser (Chrome), and B) install a new bit of software. Why not bookmark or just type stack into Google? Of which, neither options/suggestions are browser specific. Also you did go on about something else unrelated. I didn't down vote maliciously, I just thought your answer was off track.

Comment: @James  Setting up `so whatever` is built into Chrome, and I said it wasn't a domain.  Pushing back against buying more domains...even if cheap and available, is something worth mentioning. Domain squatters will disagree, but the internet itself started as being based on decentralization. Be it social networks or domain names, we need to be thinking about decentralized approaches instead of pouring more money into a flawed and unnecessary system of domain squatters and TLDs printing more money.  Decentralized trust networks can work, e.g. [FreedomBox](https://freedomboxfoundation.org/)

Comment: Add software/make changes to settings - whatever. My point is it's a long winded process when other just as simple options already exist that are not limited to specific browsers. Edit your answer and I'll remove the dvote

Comment: @James I change my philosophies when I hear good arguments and reasons for changing them, not for "points". And I stand by my declaration that a good reason for not buying more domains--in addition to those already mentioned--is "it puts money toward a purpose that isn't just unproductive, but actually counter-productive...as it creates a weak leak in traffic shaping and an ongoing unpredictable cost, regulated by a hierarchical authority of self-appointed power." If all the money piled into that system were used to build a decentralized trust network we could solve this problem for everyone.

Comment: "Unpredictable cost"? "Self appointed power"? In a world where price inflation grossly outgrows salary rises by 4 times, and super market price hikes force common people to buy cheaper low quality food, and I am forced by my government to complete census surveys which I can be fined a month's wage *by my government* if I do not complete, having the freedom of choice *to buy or not buy* what could be a really great domain name for around £3.99 is still pretty good value for money. Most things have a central control company or body, how else can something be regulated and maintained?

Comment: @James Other things are worth making a stand against--great. But I got into programming because I *thought* we were building a world with fewer limitations. e.g. once we got digital music we could make copies and not worry about the limits of physical media. Then dolts put in DRM; worse because you can't loan it out. If you buy the name James and someone else named James with equally valid claim to it can't use it, that's a problem. Commercializing words on a coercive global market reinvents the real-estate market. Stop dreaming: unless the dream is to cash in and screw everyone else, I guess?